# Swift pass-in variables in closures

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, closures

I need to write a function for a class that enumerates through an array in the class using a closure. When calling the function from elsewhere, I need the index of the current array available for me in the closure. I know how to write the function, but how would I make the index (and other variables) available when calling?

**P.S.**

This should be similar to how an SKNode in SpriteKit has enumerate through children function with the child node being available to the passed in closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Maybe like this?

```
class MyClass {
    var ary:[String] = ["foo","bar","baz"]

    func enumerateArray(block: (String, Int, inout Bool) -> Void) {
        var stop = false
        for e in enumerate(ary) {
            block(e.element, e.index, &stop)
            if stop {
                break
            }
        }
    }
}


let obj = MyClass()

obj.enumerateArray { str, idx, stop in
    println("\(idx): \(str)")
    if str == "bar" {
        stop = true
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
0: foo
1: bar
```